# What may the reason of change in app signature even i used the same keystore for android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I have published an app at Play Store. Now i made some changes in my application and used the same  key store with key alias and key password to generate signed apk with new version. When i tried to update this app, it says that the previous version have different app signature,

here is the list which i have changed in new version

- Changed the Launcher activity
- Added new activities
- added two more receivers
- added more use permissions

If you need Manifest of my previous and new version app then i will upload it

This from logcat while updating app

09-11 11:41:13.591 18410-18437/? I/seatbelt: Scan for verification results 'clean' = com.vovoapps.freesms

09-11 11:41:14.391 2730-2913/? I/MSTG: com.vovoapps.freesms is installing..

09-11 11:41:14.451 2730-2913/? W/PackageManager: Package com.vovoapps.freesms signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Comment: may be you have uploaded full signature apk,try to upload full jar signature apk, and change the version code and version name of your app from gradle

Comment: Please show the exact error message which you get.

Comment: no i used V1 Jar Signature,

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 09-11 11:41:13.591 18410-18437/? I/seatbelt: Scan for verification results 'clean' = com.vovoapps.freesms
09-11 11:41:14.391 2730-2913/? I/MSTG: com.vovoapps.freesms is installing..
09-11 11:41:14.451 2730-2913/? W/PackageManager: Package com.vovoapps.freesms signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i added log cat result

Comment: Did you get any error when uploading the update to your Google Play Console? Do you get this error when installing the app from Google Play? What device are you installing on? Is this the device you used for testing during development? Did you install the APK signed with the debug signature? This can explain why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the certificates of both the apk's by using below commands.

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk
```

If its not same then you might have missed something

Comment: should i check it for both versions?

Comment: how will you compare without checking both versions?

Comment: i checked both have same Signatures,Certificate fingerprints and Extensions

Comment: ohh strange! am assuming you have downloaded your older apk from playstore then checked the certificate.

Comment: i think i have enabled Google Play App Signing

Comment: I am facing the same issues as the asker. I ran this command for my app. And the only difference in output between the APK that is installed on my phone and the new APK is an extra space after: "Extensions:".

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I kept looking and couldn't solve it. Then finally I found the answer. I searched for all the apk's ever generated by me and then put all of them, one by one, on an online apk signature verifying site.

Fortunately, one of the apk had the same signature as the one displayed on developer console in error. So I went to that apk's folder and took the `.jks` file and signed my apk with that `.jks`.

This resolved the issue. I would say that you must have used keys of any of your other app mistakenly instead of the one which are in the project folder. So go and check signatures of all your `.jks` files and see which ones match the required one.