# Signature Mismatch according to Android PackageManager. No difference according to keytool

Tags: android, apk, keytool, jar-signing

**The situation**

We create and distribute apps on an internal/corporate app store. I have now created a new version of an app from a different computer.

**The goal**

Create a new version of our app that users can install without manuall uninstalling the previous version.

**The problem**

When I try to install the app on an Android phone that has the old version installed I get the following error message in logcat:

```
02-12 15:09:29.327 3480-3605/? W/PackageManager: Package xxx.xxx.xxx signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
```

**The obvious solution that does not work**

I did make sure to use the same keystore and certificate from the keystore.

Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149579/357601) I found that there is actually no difference in certificates for the two apps.

I ran `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile` on two files:

1. the pulled apk from the phone
2. the apk I just build

There is no difference between the two outputs.

**The question**

What else can cause this error message and how can I solve that?